Django Obtaining access path error for static resources
I used Django to configure a default avatar path in static/images, but the system always looks for the default avatar file in media/images.
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/',null=True, blank=True,default='images/默认头像.jpeg')

settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('myapp.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


profile.html
<img src="{% if request.user.profile.avatar %}{{ request.user.profile.avatar.url }}{% else %}{% static "images/默认头像.jpeg" %}{% endif %}" alt="头像" class="avatar-img">


media path：/Users/cai.wang/PycharmProjects/myweb/media
default image path：/Users/cai.wang/PycharmProjects/myweb/static/images/默认头像.jpeg
Log information
Not Found: /media/images/默认头像.jpeg
"GET /media/images/%E9%BB%98%E8%AE%A4%E5%A4%B4%E5%83%8F.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 4224
It should have gone to static/images to get the image instead of going to media/images

it should be like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/StudentPost/example.jpeg this url will server your images, adjust url with respect to the project

You need to append the static paths as well:
urlpatterns = (
    [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    ]
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
)
But that is likely not the problem, you need to put your 默认头像.jpeg not only in /static/images/, but also in /media/images/.
